# How to Close Browser after a Test Fails during Parallel Testing

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Trying to close the browser when a test fails in Selenium. Tried to include an AfterMethod but not browser is still not closing on fail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my java class:

```
public class googleTestClass extends Methods{

public void executeGoogle() throws InterruptedException {
    this.goToURL("https://www.google.com");
    this.enterValue("name","q","google test 1");
}

@Test
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {

    googleTestClass object1;
    object1 = new googleTestClass();
    object1.launchBrowser();
    object1.executeGoogle();
}

@Test
public void test2() throws InterruptedException {

    googleTestClass object2;
    object2 = new googleTestClass();
    object2.launchBrowser();
    object2.executeGoogle();
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Here is the mentioned Methods class:
    // import statements

```
public class Methods {

public WebDriver driver;

public void launchBrowser() {System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

public void goToURL(String url) {
    driver.get(url);
}

    public void enterValue(String htmltype, String identifier, String value) throws InterruptedException {
    if (htmltype == "id") {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(value);
        element.submit();
    }
    if (htmltype =="name") {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(identifier));
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(value);
        element.submit();
    }

    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

Here is the used testNG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">

  <test thread-count="5" name="Test" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
         <class name="webDrivertests.googleTestClass">
            <methods>
                <include name ="test1"/>
                <include name ="test2"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Is the `AfterMethod` not being reached because it is written incorrectly or does the problem lies in `driver.quit?` Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: If you will handle code of block with try catch it will throws exception within try catch method, but if its not handle with try catch then it will fail @Test. If test fail, it will not execute after method and it got skip because of failure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you run the Test class and `@AfterMethod` is called, it is trying to quit from the driver that belongs to the top class but not to the classes which are instantiated inside the methods. Here is a small example for better understanding :

JUnit test class :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.After;

public class intTestClass extends Methods{

    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        intTestClass object1;
        object1 = new intTestClass();
        object1.setInt();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("testInt is: "+ testInt);
    }
}
```

And the Methods class :

```
public class Methods {

    public int testInt = 0;

    public void setInt() {
        testInt = 1;
    }

}
```

Here, when you run the JUnit test, what you expect is that the `testInt` value to be printed as 1. However, the method with the annotation `@After(@AfterMethod for testng)` checks the value of the `testInt` variable which belongs to the **top level** intTestClass rather than the *intTestClass* that is instantiated inside the `test1()` method.

Therefore, we see the output as :

```
testInt is: 0
```

If we apply this to your scenario, what you need to do is that move your `launchBrowser()` method inside your test class and call the method with an `@BeforeClass` annotation.